# Python to C for loop conversion

Tags: python, c

I have the following python code:

```
r = range(1,10)
r_squared = []

for item in r:
    print item
    r_squared.append(item*item)
```

How would I convert this code to C? Is there something like a mutable array in C or how would I do the equivalent of the python append?

Comment: Use linked lists, there's a couple of libraries available.

Comment: If you read the code, you know in advance what the length of the array will be, and you know that nothing is going to try to read it while it's any other length, so is there any *reason* to try to replicate that feature of python lists?

Comment: then Go for Vectors in the C.http://happybearsoftware.com/implementing-a-dynamic-array.html

Comment: 1) Do you mean `C`, or is `C++` allowed? `std::vector<>` is similar in mnay ways to `list`. 2) Do you need to the array to be expandable, or will you know the size of the array at its creation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simple array in c.Arrays in the C are `Homogenous`

```
int arr[10];
int i = 0;
for(i=0;i<sizeof(arr);i++) 
{ 
  arr[i] = i; // Initializing each element seperately 
}
```

Try using `vectors` in C go through this [link](http://happybearsoftware.com/implementing-a-dynamic-array.html)

```
/ vector-usage.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include "vector.h"

int main() {
  // declare and initialize a new vector
  Vector vector;
  vector_init(&vector);

  // fill it up with 150 arbitrary values
  // this should expand capacity up to 200
  int i;
  for (i = 200; i > -50; i--) {
    vector_append(&vector, i);
  }

  // set a value at an arbitrary index
  // this will expand and zero-fill the vector to fit
  vector_set(&vector, 4452, 21312984);

  // print out an arbitrary value in the vector
  printf("Heres the value at 27: %d\n", vector_get(&vector, 27));

  // we're all done playing with our vector, 
  // so free its underlying data array
  vector_free(&vector);
}
```

Comment: OP needs his array to be extendable.

Comment: @simonzack how do you know? That's not in OP's question at all. Just because that's how Python manages adding to lists doesn't mean it's part of OP's requirements....

Comment: @AdamSmith Thats what I imagined he meant by "mutable array".

Comment: @simonzack "mutable" just means that it can change. Unless he gives us code that shows that a list must GROW in size or meet a specific size unknowable at compile time, it's hard to say what he means by a "mutable array" but I take your meaning.

Comment: Sigh. It's obvious that the OP wants an "array" that grows as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in C are mutable by default, in that you can write `a[i] = 3`, just like Python lists.

However, they're fixed-length, unlike Python lists.

For your problem, that should actually be fine. You know the final size you want; just create an array of that size, and assign to the members.

But of course there are problems for which you *do* need `append`.

---

Writing a simple library for appendable arrays (just like Python lists) is a pretty good learning project for C. You can also find plenty of ready-made implementations if that's what you want, but not in the standard library.

The key is to not use a stack array, but rather memory allocated on the heap with [`malloc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/malloc.html). Keep track of the pointer to that memory, the capacity, and the used size. When the used size reaches the capacity, multiply it by some number (play with different numbers to get an idea of how they affect performance), then [`realloc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/realloc.html). That's just about all there is to it. (And if you look at the [CPython source for the `list` type](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/135fc23e475c/Objects/listobject.c), that's basically the same thing it's doing.)

Here's an example. You'll want to add some error handling (`malloc` and `realloc` can return `NULL`) and of course the rest of the API beyond `append` (especially a `delete` function, which will call `free` on the allocated memory), but this should be enough to show you the idea:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
  int *i;
  size_t len;
  size_t capacity;
} IntArray;

IntArray int_array_make() {
  IntArray a = {
    .i = malloc(10 * sizeof(int)),
    .len = 0,
    .capacity = 10
  };
  return a;
}

void int_array_append(IntArray *a, int value) {
  if (a->len+1 == a->capacity) {
    size_t new_capacity = (int)(a->capacity * 1.6);
    a->i = realloc(a->i, new_capacity * sizeof(int));
    a->capacity = new_capacity;
  }
  a->i[a->len++] = value;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  IntArray a = int_array_make();
  for (int i = 0; i != 50; i++)
    int_array_append(&a, i);
  for (int i = 0; i != a.len; ++i)
    printf("%d ", a.i[i]);
  printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

c doesnt have any way of dynamically increasing the size of the array like in python. arrays here are of fixed length

if you know the size of the array that you will be using, u can use this kind of declaration, like this

```
int arr[10];
```

or if you would want to add memery on the fly (in runtime), use malloc call along with structure (linked lists)

Comment: Why switch from arrays to linked lists just so you can append? They're no easier to build, and you're giving up advantages that an experienced Python programmer is likely to expect (e.g., constant-time random-access indexing, with a very similar syntax to Python's) for those that he's unlikely to be looking for (e.g., constant-time insert or delete in the middle of the list).

Comment: This isn't true anyway, among other things you can `realloc`.

Comment: i am not advicing him to switch from array to link list. i am just letting him know what options he have in C. i gave the array[10] example coz he seem to be knowing the size of the array from beforehand. i gave the linked list example to let him know there is  a way in C to dynamically increase the size of the array.